# getting segmentation fault with set

Tags: c++, set

What is wrong with my code. I am getting segmentation fault on submission.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--){
        int n,k;
        cin>>n>>k;
        int x;
        set<int> s;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            cin>>x;
            s.insert(x);
        }
        int m;
        int ans=0;
        for(int i=0;i<k;i++){
            m=*s.rbegin();
            ans+=m;
            s.insert(m/2);
            s.erase(m);

        }
        cout<<ans<<"\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Constraints for the problem are:

1 ≤ T ≤ 10

1 ≤ N ≤ 10^5

0 ≤ K ≤ 10^5

0 ≤ Si ≤10^5

Comment: And you have tested for the edge-cases yourself? What if the input is invalid? *Always* check for invalid input, *never* trust the input even if it's supposed to be within some limits.

Answer (score 1):

With `n=1`, `k=2`, `x=0`, you will insert `0` into set, then insert `0` again (which does nothing), then remove `0` from the set. On the next `k` round, you will try to read the `rbegin()` of an empty set, resulting in a crash.

Comment: so what should I use instead of set?     since I want to insert duplicate and it should be sorted;

Comment: @Rohit Kumar Just use a `std::vector` and `std::sort` it.

Answer (score 0):

If you erase last element, the container is empty.

Then the attempt to dereference the iterator cause undefined behavior (probably program crash).

I suggest you to check if there are *any* (at least one) elements, and if not, break the loop.

Example

```
for(int i=0;i<k && s.size()!=0 ;i++){
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that your set is empty or not before accessing the element of to set.

```
if(!s.empty()){
        m=*s.rbegin();
        ans+=m;
        s.insert(m/2);
        s.erase(m);
}
```

Comment: thank u!                                                                                                        
but what should I use instead of set? since I want to insert duplicate and it should be sorted;

Comment: You should use multiset.It allows the duplicate values and it also maintains sorting.

Comment: i got it. thank you